# Getting unhandled exception error when trying to read a file while using try/catch block

Tags: java, exception, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to create a program which reads a .java file then places each line into an ArrayList:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

class H01_43 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name.");
        String fileName = userInput.nextLine();
        TextFile file1 = new TextFile();

        file1.createArray(fileName);

        userInput.close();
    }
}

class TextFile{

    public TextFile(){ 

    }

    public void createArray(String pFileName){
        String currentLine = "";
        ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<>();    

        try{   
            Scanner userFile = new Scanner(newFile(pFileName));        
            while(userFile.hasNextLine()){
                currentLine = userFile.nextLine();
                mList.add(currentLine);

            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException exception){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }finally{
            userFile.close();
        }
    }

}
```

I keep getting the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:
>    Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
>
> at TextFile.createArray(H01_43 make a java file into txt file.java:47)
>    at H01_43.main(H01_43 make a java file into txt file.java:27)

I tried working with a tutor who said my code looks fine, but somehow I continue generating this error and therefore can not compile or test my code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The first thing to do is turn off whatever is allowing you to run code that won't compile. It's almost never a good idea - and in this case it's confusing  because you're getting an exception (which is usually due to something bad happening at execution time) but the real cause is that your code won't compile. Unfortunately the code you've shown us won't compile for *different* reasons - you haven't shown us the `newFile` method. Look at the compilation errors closely - your IDE should help you pinpoint where they are. Fix them all before you try to run,.

Comment: show you complete code

Comment: It took longer than I like to admit for me to figure this out. However, I think one of the biggest issues was VS Code (or perhaps my inability to use it properly). Because after making my changes my code was able to compile and run when using my command prompt window but not when using powershell in VS Code. Any one know why?

Answer (score 0):

I have actually been struggling with this problem since last semester and just figured it out. Here is my method with the changes:

```
public void createArray(String pFileName){
    String currentLine = "";
    ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<>();    

    try{   
        Scanner userFile = new Scanner(new File(pFileName));        
        while(userFile.hasNextLine()){
            currentLine = userFile.nextLine();
            mList.add(currentLine);

        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException exception){

    }

}
```

First problem was that newFile was supposed to be new File but my main issue was that I needed to remove finally and userFile.close(). Am unsure why this is the case and would appreciate it if anyone has some insight for me.